# Merge first column that has the same second column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `INNER JOIN` query that returns this result:

```
first column | second column
     2       |       15 
     5       |       16
     6       |       16
     5       |       18
     6       |       22
```

I want to output them in my page like this:

```
first column | second column
     2       |       15 
     5,6     |       16
             |       18
             |       22
Total first column: 2
```

It will combine the first column that has the same second column. And value of the combined first column will be share between them.

And would also tell the total first column (which in the example is 2).

I'm still trying with this code:

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firsttb.firstcolumn, secondtb.secondcolumn FROM firsttb INNER JOIN secondtb ON firsttb.connectid = secondtb.connectid WHERE firsttb.getid = ? ORDER BY secondtb.secondcolumn")){

  $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET["getid"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($firstcolumn,$secondcolumn);

  $lastid = 0;
  $total = 0;
  $combine = "";

    while($stmt->fetch()){

      if($lastid == $secondcolumn){
        $combine = $combine."".$firstcolumn;
        $lastid = $secondcolumn;
      }

      else {
        $totalrow = $totalrow + 1;
        $lastid = $secondcolumn;
        $combine = $secondcolumn;

        echo $combine." | ".$secondcolumn."<br>";

      }

    }
  $stmt->close();
  echo "Total first column: ".$totalrow;
}
```

But only get this output:

```
first column | second column
     2       |       15 
     5       |       16
     5       |       18
     6       |       22
Total first column: 4
```

It is okay to scrap my code and create it with your own. Just want to look for the right idea.

Comment: try [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) with Group Concat

Comment: and also the output you want is having column with null values. so try using [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) instead.

Comment: why are you not putting anything on column1 where column2  = 18 or 22?

Comment: @pala_ - it is just the output, not the table itself. It is the output I wanted for my page, the one that I'm getting from the table using the query is in the first illustration. It means that 16,18 and 22 is now under the 5 and 6. Remember that I only given an example, 5 and 6 is a string in ny original code, and they will be combined if they have the same `second column`.

Comment: i ask because for the purposes of display, it doesn't seem to make any logical sense to not associate a value with the second columns, and if that were allowed, as the others have said `group_concat` makes this problem trivial. also - what if they are duplicated on more than one value of column2? which one would you like to use? what if a single value in column1, has more than one value in column2, but doesnt share it with another column1?

Comment: @pala_ If two or more data in the first column have the same second column, they will share all the other second column data that they have. A single match will make them merge.

Comment: what if they match more than once? eg `(2 | 15, 2 | 13, 3 | 15, 3 | 13)` -- which group takes precedence?

Comment: Then, 2 and 3 will be `2,3` and they will cover all the second column. Not repeating the `2,3` Like this: `(2, 3 | 15, /n | 13)`